# Virtual Environment and App Inside The Project Root

Tags: django, virtualenv, django-ckeditor

We are using virtual env inside our project folder. (with django 1.4)

```
ProjectRoot
   - app1
   - app2
   - env
   - ckeditor
   - settings.py
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

We are using `django-ckeditor` inside of project. In local environment this app working perfect. But in server (apache), `django-ckeditor` installed anywhere with pip. The error:

```
▶ Local vars
   /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor/views.py in upload
   create_thumbnail(upload_filename) ...
▶ Local vars
  /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor/views.py in create_thumbnail
  image = Image.open(filename) ..
```

How could I use ckeditor inside the app? Because from error it seems that project using `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor/` one.

Comment: if you take down `ckeditor` folder alone from `site-packages` and put it in project root, then installed apps `ckeditor` will work.

Comment: It is in Project root. There is not any installed ckeditor in env. But the ckeditor out of project root is working (django-ckeditor==4.0.2)

Comment: the structure you shown in the code sample not clear, can you clarify it.?

Comment: yes, outside of the project env will work, You may need tell django to look inside the project

Comment: The solution is define path in WSGIDaemonProcess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60625/discussion-between-rajasimon-and-thenone).